# Python loop not fully looping

Tags: python, syntax

Whenever I execute my loop in Python, for both numbers and symbols, I am not looping through my numbers entirely. This might just be a beginner syntax error, as I am new to python, but I'm not sure what it is.

```
if sizeOfPassword == 9:
    maxNum = 1
    maxSym = 1
if sizeOfPassword > 9:
    maxNum = 5
    maxSym = 4

checkNum = 0
checkSym = 0

while checkSym < 4 and checkNum < 5:
    if checkSym < maxSym:
        password += chr(random.randint(33, 47))
        checkSym = checkSym + 1
    if checkNum < maxNum:
        password += chr(random.randint(48, 57))
        checkNum = checkNum + 1
    

while len(password) < sizeOfPassword:
    password += chr(random.randint(65, 90))
        
l = list(password)
random.shuffle(l)
password = ''.join(l)

print("Your new random password is: " + password)
```

I get values as such when maxNum = 5:

```
0'04%-5'VU
4V/"201"Z'
/T/8O951#*
R-84%("54K
```

Im looking for these values to have 5 numbers. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think the problem is here: `while checkSym < 4 and checkNum < 5:`. You want that `and` to be an `or`. Right now you exit out of the loop as soon as one of these two conditions is met, you probably want to wait until both have been met.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify to:

```
password_list = [chr(random.randint(48, 57)) for i in range(5)] + [chr(random.randint(33, 47)) for i in range(4)]

password_list
['3', '0', '1', '1', '8', '+', ',', '#', ',']

random.shuffle(password_list)

password = "".join(password)

password
'1+018#,,3'
```